# Here Venue API support for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, here-api

I wanted to develop native Indoor mobile app in Xamarin to support Windows,  Android and iOS platform.  Does Here Venue API support this.

Comment: If answer be helpful , remembre to mark it when have time .

Answer (score 0):

Yes the HERE Venue Maps API fully supports indoor routing, detailed venue information and venue maps and map images. See the documentation:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/venue-maps/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html
https://developer.here.com/documentation/venue-maps/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-routing-2.html